# what is the usage of three js Object3D.matrixWorldAutoUpdate and updateMatrixWorld() api?

Tags: three.js

since three.js [r144](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r144), there is some matrix world update properties and apis like:

```
 Object3D
.matrixWorldAutoUpdate
.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate 
.updateMatrixWorld ( force : Boolean )
.updateWorldMatrix ( updateParents : Boolean, updateChildren : Boolean ) :
```

When I try to playaround these, I can not find the right way of using this. when I try to update matrixworld directly like:

```
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    cube.matrixWorldAutoUpdate = false;
    scene.add(cube);
    ...
    function render() {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      
      // Rotate our cube
      x += 0.1;
      // cube.matrix.makeTranslation(x,0,0);
      cube.matrixWorld.makeTranslation(x,0,0);
      // cube.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
      // cube.updateMatrix();
      cube.updateMatrixWorld(true);
      
      controls.update();
      
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

I see no cube moving in rendering at all, matrixworld not changed every frame. I got more confused by these new properties names and usage.

Question: What's the usage and design purpose of these properties and apis?
Am I doing something wrong about the matrixworld?
is there a way to move the object3d by directly change the matrixworld?